# uiview and uitableview in same uiviewcontroller showing different sizes on iphone, ipad

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiview, uiviewcontroller

[image]I have a UIView and a UITableView under one UIViewController. Pl see image below. In top level view controller, I need the UIView (CheckoutNTotal) with few buttons and textfields. Below that I want the UITableView. This shows up fine in simulator or on actual device for iphone. for ipad, the CheckoutNTotal shows up much large on screen. i even said height constraint of 130 for UIView. What could be going on? Here are the warnings I get in xcode 7.1

Thank you

Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(
    "<_UILayoutSupportConstraint:0x7c2d2790 V:[_UILayoutGuide:0x7c50b360(64)]>",
    "<_UILayoutSupportConstraint:0x7c2d3ba0 V:|-(0)-[_UILayoutGuide:0x7c50b360]   (Names: '|':UIView:0x7c50bd20 )>",
    "",
    "",
    "",
    ""
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint

[image]

Comment: you need to show us what kind of constraints u given to ur views

Comment: also pleaSe note that, you should never touch the width and height constraints unless you really need them. Most probably auto layout will use trailing and leading top and bottom to adjust the view dimensions as per the screen size.

Comment: Thanks Mr.T. I just uploaded the constraints. I removed the height constraint on view. Am a newbie. Autolayout is the one that drives me nuts.

Comment: remove the centre Y constraints when you already given leading constraints for the element

Comment: remove all the constraints for thecheckOutNtotal or edit the constraints in storyboard. Just give leading and trailing to superview, and top to tableview and bottom to superview if your view is below the tableview

Comment: my CheckoutNTotal view is above tableview. i don't want any overlapping between these two. is there anyway you can help me over chat or something? or is that against the forum rules?

Comment: do u use team viewer ?

Comment: i deleted all constraints in storyboard and did as you said. seems to be working fine! Thank you.